# Android how to get image resource?

Tags: android, imageview

I want to check if an imageview is displaying  a certain image, how do I do that? Or maybe just if it has an image at all?

Comment: Did you try http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#getDrawable() ?

Comment: @mirco.widmer You should put that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the getDrawable()-method:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#getDrawable()

Answer (score 0):

```
   if(!yourImageView.getDrawable().equals(null)){
    // the View is displaying some image
     } else {
      //no image
     }
```